# USB Serial/CDC function driver

Tags: c, linux, usb, device, usbserial

OS: Ubuntu Linux 10.10
Kernel: 2.6.35-30

Query: I need to establish a robust communication between a Windows process and an embedded device on the above platform. What can be a possible solution in this case? Socket programming has already been ruled out in this case. It may sound to you as a very fundamental question but I am new to this domain and will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you clarify your question?

1. Do you really mean "Windows USB device driver"?
2. What is your full setup?  (For example:

   *The host system is running Ubuntu (Kernel 2.6...) attached to one of it's USB ports is a USB to serial adapter which is connected to the serial port of an embedded device.  I need to communicate with the  embedded device through a program I'm writing in C.*)

Comment: My bad. I should not have written Windows USB device. Let's take it as a windows process which tries to communicate to the embedded Linux device through USB. I would like to know a robust mechanism to do that.

You rightly assumed the programming language to be C and also the platform to be Ubuntu 10.10 (kernel 2.6.35-30).

Comment: Does your USB adapter create a Windows COM port? You should be able to tell under Windows Device Manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a serial communication of a USB device in Ubuntu, then your device name is something like /dev/ttyUSB(some number). This will appear in your ls command as and when you connect the device.

If you are looking for a simulator for a serial device then I suggest using socat. If you need a reference for socat command, try using this link [serial port simulator in linux](http://www.codersource.net/C/CMiscellaneous/SerialPortSimulatorinLinux.aspx)